# How to add new cells to tableview with some delay in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I want to add new table view cell with some delay. I'm using following block to create delay.

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
```

It's working fine but if i switch to other tab and comeback during the delay. some empty duplicate cells are getting added.

I'm trying to add new cell with help of following code

```
  delay(1){
                    NSLog("lesson card")
                    let lessonCard : LessonsLauncher = messageCard.object as! LessonsLauncher
                    self.messageCards.append(messageCard)
                    self.currentMessageCard = lessonCard
                    let lessonCardOptions : MessageCard = MessageCard()
                    lessonCardOptions.viewType = .LESSON_CARD_OPTIONS
                    self.messageCards.append(lessonCardOptions)
                    let chatMessage = lessonCard.toChatMessage()
                    ChatMessage.createChatMessage(chatMessage)
                    let indexpath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messageCards.count-2, inSection: 0)
                    let indexpath2 = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messageCards.count-1, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexpath1,indexpath2], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
                    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexpath2, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
                   // self.nextIndex = lessonCard.next
                }
```

Comment: Where/how are you firing this method

Comment: You need to stop the delay when switching views

Comment: How do i do that? @MikeSchmidt

Comment: I suggest you look at NSTimer rather than using dispatch_after

Comment: @Paulw11 Tried it. getting same output

Comment: call `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Paulw11 did that still getting same output

Comment: Then you need to do some more debugging.  What do you have in your `self.messageCards` array when you return to the view controller? Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not changing  self.messageCards when i return to the view controller except adding new message in as u can see in that delay block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120204/discussion-between-paulw11-and-chandra-mohan).

Comment: @Paulw11 Pls find below cellforrowindexpath code

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried to find where it's going wrong but I couldn't find it. I think only explaination i have is i'm running background thread to wait for 1 second and adding it to main queue to add new cell. during that 1 second if switch tabs it's going wrong

Comment: Try and create a simpler [mcve] that reproduces the problem so that you can show more code and we can see where you are going wrong

Comment: Okay. i'll do that.